# symfony 1.4: how to know the if a column of a model is a foreign key?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I expected that something like this below worked, but `getColumns()` doesn't return a `sfDoctrineColumn` object..

```
$beautyPropertiesTable = Doctrine::getTable('BeautyProperty');
$beautyPropertiesTable->getColumns();
```

You know, `sfDoctrineColumn` has a method called `isForeignKey()` but I don't know from where can I get a `sfDoctrineColumn` object..

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Example taken from lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/test/unit/sfDoctrineColumnTest.php

$column = new sfDoctrineColumn('column_name', Doctrine::getTable('BeautyProperty')); 

var_dump($column->isPrimaryKey());
```